# Why does document.cookie exist and when is it used by DOM in a browser?

Tags: javascript, http, dom, cookies, https

I am a bit confused by the *document.cookie* property: why does this property exist at all, and under what scenario the DOM, when being rendered in a browser, want to access it?

The examples that I can find, such as https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie, only tell me how to read or write a cookie, but I wonder **why** the DOM need to access the cookie at all.

Consider an HTTP response, both the web document and the cookie are sent from the origin server, what is the reason that the web document wants to access the cookie only after it is loaded into the browser? Why can't such jobs be done at the server side and save client's effort and time? And based on my understanding, cookie is used for the server to identify session or user and will be attached by the browser when a request is sent to the server, which does not contain any meaningful content from human being's perspective, so what practical use of cookies in the DOM context?

Comment: It's a way for the client to read and write persistent site settings that the server needs to know too, which is useful. Example on a forum: number of posts to display per page

Comment: I think its purpose it's to be used by javascript, simple as that.

Comment: @Romka, yes of course it is to be used by JS, but I wonder why it is needed at all.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, is there any concrete example, please? Why such jobs must be done within Cookies?

Comment: *Example on a forum: number of posts to display per page* is a pretty concrete example. This sort of thing doesn't *have* to be done in cookies, but putting such a setting into cookies makes good sense to me, at least for anonymous users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's meant to be accessed by JavaScript. As JS is built to interface with the page DOM, it uses that to set/read cookies. For example (and this is gonna sound very meta but bear with me), you can programmatically set a cookie for a user if they hit the "I agree" on a cookie consent notification. JS can then search for that cookie to see if the user has agreed, and then decide whether or not to display the notification, which itself is a process that interacts with DOM.